# O que significa covariante e contravariante do TypeVar do módulo typing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tipagem

Ao utilizar o módulo [`typing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) do Python, disponível nas versões 3.5+, é possível definir novos tipos com o uso da estrutura `TypeVar`.

```py
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')  # Pode ser qualquer tipo
A = TypeVar('A', str, bytes)  # Necessita ser uma string ou sequência de bytes
```

Além disso, é possível definir o tipo como covariante ou contravariante.

```py
T = TypeVar('T', covariant=True)
T = TypeVar('T', contravariant=True)
```

O que são essas duas opções para o novo tipo? Quais são as peculiaridades de cada uma e quando se deve (pode) usá-las?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine que estamos programando um jogo. O nosso jogo possui vários objetos tridimensionais, incluindo caixas de papelão. Uma forma de representar isso em código seria assim:

```py
class Figura3D():
    pass

class Cubo(Figura3D):
    pass

class CaixaDePapelao(Cubo):
    pass
```

Há uma classe base para representar todas as figuras tridimensionais, depois uma classe para representar todas as figuras tridimensionais cúbicas, depois uma classe pra representar especificamente uma caixa de papelão, que é, obviamente, uma figura tridimensional cúbica.

O nosso jogo precisa de uma classe responsável por renderizar coisas na tela, que seria mais ou menos assim:

```py
T = TypeVar('T')

class Renderizador(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, x: T):
        pass
```

Perceba que a classe `Renderizador` possui um argumento genérico de tipo `T`, pois ele deve ser capaz de renderizar qualquer coisa.

O código do nosso jogo ainda possui uma função que serve especificamente para renderizar cubos.

```py
def executar_render(render: Renderizador[Cubo]):
    pass
```

Ela recebe um renderizador de cubos e o utiliza para desenhar o cubo na tela.

Agora, sabendo que um objeto da classe `CaixaDePapelao` é também um `Cubo` (devido à herança), faz sentido passar um `Renderizador[CaixaDePapelao]` para a função acima, correto?

Não!

O código seguinte é recusado pelo mypy:

```py
render_caixa_de_papelao = Renderizador(CaixaDePapelao())
executar_render(render_caixa_de_papelao)
```

> error: Argument 1 to "executar_render" has incompatible type "Renderizador[CaixaDePapelao]"; expected "Renderizador[Cubo]"

Isso acontece porque o `TypeVar('T')` por padrão é **invariante**. Isso significa que suas subclasses e superclasses *não são compatíveis com ele*. No entanto, se trocarmos a declaração para:

```py
T = TypeVar('T', covariant=True)
```

O erro desaparece e o mypy aceita que renderizadores de caixa de papelão sejam usados no lugar de renderizadores de cubos.

Resumindo:

- Um tipo **invariante** não aceita subclasses ou superclasses
- Um tipo **covariante** aceita subclasses, mas não superclasses
- Um tipo **contravariante** aceita superclasses, mas não subclasses

Agora resta a pergunta:

> Como se chamam os tipos que aceitam tanto subclasses quanto superclasses?

Se chamam **bivariantes** e não são suportados pelo Python.